# Restriction of explicit object parameter in lambda with capture

Tags: c++, lambda, c++23

In C++23, lambda-expression supports an explicit object parameter (a.k.a. "Deducing this"). I found strange restriction for lambda with capturing at [[expr.prim.lambda]/p5](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-5).

> Given a lambda with a lambda-capture, the type of the explicit object parameter, if any, of the lambda's function call operator (possibly instantiated from a function call operator template) shall be either:
>
> - the closure type,
> - a class type derived from the closure type, or
> - a reference to a possibly cv-qualified such type.
>
> [Example 2:
>
> ```cpp
> struct C {
>   template <typename T>
>   C(T);
> };
>
> void func(int i) {
>   int x = [=](this auto&&) { return i; }();  // OK
>   int y = [=](this C) { return i; }();       // error
>   int z = [](this C) { return 42; }();       // OK
> }
> ```
>
> -- end example]

Question: Why is there such restriction for lambda with capture only? Are there any implementation issues?

Comment: I don't think this needs language-lawyer tag since you're already citing reference from the standard and also asking about possible implementation issues.

Comment: I mean that "implementation issues" is for C++ compiler.

Comment: https://wg21.link/expr.prim.lambda.capture#11.sentence-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a few things at play here.

First, lambda captures have no names. So if we just take a regular old C++11 lambda:

```cpp
void foo(int i) {
    auto f = [=](){ return i; };
}
```

`f` there captures `i`, but there is no member `f.i`. It's just that naming `i` from within the body of the lambda magically refers to that capture. There's no way to explicitly name it within the body either - within a class type you could write `i` or `this->i`, but there's no latter option for a lambda (since any use of `this` would refer to some outer captured `this` instead).

This lack of ability to name the lambda itself was one of the motivations for the deducing this feature.

Now, we can write that lambda differently:

```cpp
auto g = [=](this auto self){
    return self.i; // ??
};
```

Here, `self` is actually the lambda itself, when you call it (the expression `g()` would copy `g` into the `self` parameter). And this has to be a generic lambda, because lambdas have unnameable types - you can't write `decltype(g)` there. But... `g` is still a lambda, and lambda captures have no names. And we didn't want to suddenly add those names, so we end up with this:

```cpp
auto g2 = [=](this auto self){
    return i; // ?!?
};
```

This is, admittedly, pretty weird right? `i` here behaves the same way as `i` in the original `f` lambda - it's transformed into an access of the lambda capture. But *which* lambda? `self`.

So now because the only way to access a lambda capture in a lambda with an explicit object parameter is implicit, we need to ensure that the explicit object parameter actually *is* the lambda that we're currently defining - otherwise the code is kind of nonsensical. We captured `i` by copy into the lambda, but we don't have the lambda in scope to get `i` from, so what can we even do?

Hence the cited rule: if there is a lambda capture and an explicit object parameter, we need to ensure that the explicit object parameter is actually the lambda doing the capturing (or a type derived from it).

Had lambda captures been *named* (either initially or introduced in the C++23 along with deducing this in some form or other), then this rule wouldn't have been necessary since you'd just write `return self.i` if that's what you wanted. But this then presents a different kind of problem: how do you know what `[=]` or `[&]` actually... captures? So the oddity that implicitly naming captures works, even in the context of explicit object parameters in lambdas, is probably the least strange option in this space.

Answer (score 1):

An object (or subobject) of the closure type is needed to **access** the captures (which are members of it).

Comment: I think the question is more that this requirement seems redundant; what other type could it possibly get?

Comment: @NicolBolas Could be a type that's convertible from the closure (such as the type `C` in the cited example).

Comment: @cpplearner: The function could also be called for any other type by taking its address.